# AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime notification not working when AVPlayer's volume is changed

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

In my setup the user can tap a button to mute or unmute the `AVPlayer`. Simultaneously the video's subtitles are removed or added. But when the the AVPlayer is changed, for example from muted to unmuted, then the `NotificationCenter` does not inform me when `AVPlayer` is playing to end. I read somewhere that if `AVPlayerItem` is changed manually then I will not get any notification of `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime`. So I tried to remove the `NotificationCenter`'s observer and add a new observer to it again. But it does not work

Here is my example

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
...
   let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
   player?.isMuted = true
   if let group = asset.mediaSelectionGroup(forMediaCharacteristic: AVMediaCharacteristic.legible) {
      let localeGER = Locale(identifier: "ger")
      var options = AVMediaSelectionGroup.mediaSelectionOptions(from: group.options, with: localeGER)
      if let option = options.first {
                avoption = option
                player?.currentItem?.select(option, in: group)
      }
   }
   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(videoEnded),
                                                       name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player?.currentItem)
}
```

And here is the snippet when user tapped button

```
 @objc private func disEnableSubAudio(_ sender: UIButton) {
        isAudioOn = !isAudioOn

        if isAudioOn == false {
            let group = player!.currentItem!.asset.mediaSelectionGroup(forMediaCharacteristic: AVMediaCharacteristic.legible)
            player?.currentItem?.select(nil, in: group!)
            
            // unmute player
            player?.isMuted = false

            // check when video ended
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(videoEnded),
                                                   name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player?.currentItem)
            
        } else {
            if let group =  player?.currentItem?.asset.mediaSelectionGroup(forMediaCharacteristic: AVMediaCharacteristic.legible) {
                let localeGER = Locale(identifier: "ger")
                var options = AVMediaSelectionGroup.mediaSelectionOptions(from: group.options, with: localeGER)
                if let option = options.first {
                    player?.currentItem?.select(option, in: group)
                }
            }
            
            // mute player
            player?.isMuted = true
        }
    }
```

`AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` only works when the `AVPlayer` or `AVPlayerItem` is not changed. So how can I check when the video is ending when some changes are made ?

Comment: Why are you using two different selectors? Was that intentional?

Comment: this is a mistake. It is the same selector. I will correct it. Thanks!